# iOS: How do I know if user left the current screen?

Tags: ios

I want to build some analytics into my app and I would like to send some data when user leaves current screen, though there are multiple ways he can do so (back button, other button, sidebar menu, etc). Is there any efficient way to do this? I really don't feel like implementing it to every possible button that can lead the user to different screen.

Comment: Depending on your analytics provider you'll get this for free when you record a new screen view anyway I believe. But like Dávid said below, `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear` are the two that will be called both when pressing back, and when presenting a new screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call your function inside `viewWillDisappear`, which is called every time the current view controller is about to disappear from screen. See the [documentation of viewWillDisappear](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621485-viewwilldisappear)
Also see the view controller life cycle (thanks @Paolo for the tip) below ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW3)).
[image]

Comment: To add to this, here is the view controller life cycle: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW3

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have included the picture and the link in my answer.

Comment: I totally forgot about these methods. Thanks!